# How to use a mobile phone number or email to signin in NextAuth for react

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a backend that requires either a phone number or an email to login and recieve a jwt token. The front end is in [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) and i'm using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) to authorize users.

Here is a snippet from the `/login` page:

```
await signIn("credentials", {
  email: inputType === "email" ? values.username : "",
  phone: inputType === "number" ? values.username : "",
  password: values.password,
  // redirect: false,
  callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
})
```

And from `[...nextauth].js`:

```
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
      console.log({ credentials });

      const { email, phone, password } = credentials;

      try {
        const creds = !!phone
          ? {
              identifier: phone,
              password,
            }
          : {
              identifier: email,
              password,
            };
        console.log("LOGGING IN");
        const { data } = await axios
          .post(API_AUTH, creds, {
            headers: {
              accept: "*/*",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          })
          .then((data) => {
            return data;
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log({ err }));

        const info = getUser(data?.token);

        const user = {
          name: info?.user?.first_name + " " + info?.user?.last_name,
          email: info?.user?.email | "",
          image: info?.user?.image || "",
          sub: "",
          token: data?.token || "",
        };

        if (user) {
          return user;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        const errorMessage = e.response?.data?.message;
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }
    },
  }),
]

...


function getUser(loggintoken) {
  var _extractedtoken = loggintoken.split(".")[1];
  var _atobdata = atob(_extractedtoken);
  var _finaldata = JSON.parse(_atobdata);

  return { user: _finaldata };
}
```

The problem is that I cannot pass the phone number from the login page. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i managed to solve the issue. According to the [documenation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials), in the authorize callback of the credentials provider, it takes a function and provides `credentials` and `req` like so:

```
(credentials, req) => Promise<User>
```

So for the `/login` page:

```
await signIn("credentials", {
  identifier: values.username,
  password: values.password,
  // redirect: false,
  callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
})
```

And the `[...nextauth].js` page:

```
 CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",
    authorize: async (credentials, req) => {

      const { identifier, password } = credentials;

      const loginData = {
        identifier: req?.body?.identifier,
        password,
      };

      const { data } = await axios
        .post(API_AUTH, loginData, {
          headers: {
            accept: "*/*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
      })

     ...


       if (user) {
         return user;
       }
    },
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to how you're passing the `phone` value when calling the `signIn` function. In your code snippet, you're conditionally passing either the `email` or `phone` value based on the `inputType`, but it seems like the `signIn` function expects an object with `identifier` and `password` properties.

So you would want to update your `signIn` function to:

```js
await signIn("credentials", {
  identifier: inputType === "email" ? values.username : values.username,
  password: values.password,
  // redirect: false,
  callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
});
```

Comment: The `signIn` function will not accept anything apart from email and password. And that's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided, it looks like the /login page in your Next.js frontend is using next-auth to handle authentication, and expects either an email address or phone number as input from the user, along with a password.
The issue you're experiencing is that you're not able to pass the phone number to next-auth, even when it's being entered in the input field. One possible solution to this issue would be to modify the signIn function in the /login page to pass the phone number as a value for the identifier field in the creds object, like so:

```
// /login page

await signIn("credentials", {
  identifier: inputType === "number" ? values.username : values.email,
  password: values.password,
  callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
});
```

This way, creds will contain either the email address or phone number as the identifier, depending on what was entered into the input field. The authorize function in providers should then be able to use this information to authenticate the user and issue a JWT token.